# python 2d graphics that works with Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, graphics, 2d, simulation

I have a very large amount of data that I wish to represent in 2d. What graphics libraries would be compatible with getting data from oracles databases and still have a smooth look to them? I don't wish to use tkinter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask => please specify [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Comment: i need help choosing a library to use. It is a practical question and you have no reason to downvote me. It is not a what is your favorit____ type of question

Comment: I have not worked with many libraries other than tkinter and I am not sure how to procede. I have not tried much other than tkinter and i do not want to use that due to its clunky look

Answer (score 4):

There is no connection between the library you use for graphics and the source of the data you are representing.  When you say 2d I assume you are talking about graphs.  In that case, try matplotlib or google charts api.  Both work nicely with python and can represent your data in attractive looking 2d graphs

Comment: sorry i was not clear. I want a graphics library that can handle the large amount of data. I plan on creating a simulation of the data i have. the data is time stamps and positions

Comment: I still recommend matplotlib.  It is designed for dealing with VERY large sets of scientific data.  Manipulating the data first using scipy or numpy before building the presentation layer with matplotlib would be your best bet.

Comment: would that work well to create a simulation of hundereds of planes flying across a map? One factor I really value is how good it is going to look